# Generate object array with values from Database

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have this table:

```
id    |    product_item    |    head_count
1     |         400        |        2
2     |         401        |        5
```

desired output:

```
[
   {"product_item": 400,"head_count": 2},
   {"product_item": 401,"head_count": 5}
]
```

How do I make this desired output using Laravel or Eloquent?

Answer (score 3):

```
Follow bellow step  
(1) declare in your controller **use DB**  

(2) write Query:  
$product = DB::table('tablename')->select('col1','col2')->get(); 

(3)dd($product); OR print_r($product);  

You got the result in $product  

echo json_encode($product); 

OR if you are load your view then,  
return view('VIEW_NAME',compact('product'));  

OR return like this and got the result on your view file.

return response()->json($product);

I hope its help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model `Product` (for example) for your table, then select the data like :

```
Product::get(["product_item","head_count"]);
```

That will return a Collection of Product objects.

```
[ 
    {
        "product_item": 400,
        "head_count": 2
    },
    {
        "product_item": 401,
        "head_count": 5
    }
]
```

**NOTE:** If your table name is `products` you don't need to add the name of the table to your model since the `Product` is the singular of your table name, what means you're following conventions and laravel will detect the related table automatically.

Else you need to add the table name at the top of your Model `Product.php` like :

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'products';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = App\Product::select('product_item', 'head_count')->get()->toArray();
```

or if is one:

```
$product = App\Product::select('product_item', 'head_count')->first()->toArray();
```

or

```
    $product = App\Product::get(['product_item', 'head_count'])->toArray();
```

and return:

```
[ {Producto}, {Producto}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
$products = Products::all();

$data = [];

foreach($products as $value)
{
   $temp = [
      'product_item' => $value->product_item,
      'head_count' => $value->head_count
   ];

   array_push($data,$temp);
}

return $data;
```

**OR**

```
return response()->json($data);
```

You will get required output in $data